Creating a table/visual with calculations based off what is in another table in Power BI
I am working in Power BI and am not sure how to create another table or a visual that has calculations based off a table I already have.  This is the data I have now and also what the end result would be.  I also need to be able to filter the result by the date that is in the first table.


This looks similar to the output from office forms/quizzes or google forms. You might look into the unpivot and pivot buttons in power query behind power bi. This would unpivot your questions and answers to be side by side for each submission. So you could do a conditional column for "a" or "b" and then count those.

you can do the data transform in PQ
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMtE31zcyUtJRikwthpMmQIwQ88sHEoZAbKwUq4PQZAKTAhOmYHkULeZgk2JjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, #"Question 1a" = _t, #"Question 1b" = _t, #"Question 1c" = _t, #"Question 1d" = _t, #"Question 2a" = _t, #"Question 2b" = _t, #"Question 2c" = _t, #"Question 2d" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Question 1a", type text}, {"Question 1b", type text}, {"Question 1c", Int64.Type}, {"Question 1d", Int64.Type}, {"Question 2a", type text}, {"Question 2b", type text}, {"Question 2c", Int64.Type}, {"Question 2d", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Demoted Headers"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Promoted Headers", {"Date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Date", "Question"}, {"Attribute", "Date"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each if Value.Type([Value])=type number then [Value] else null),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if [Custom] = null then [Value] else null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Value"}),
    #"Inserted Last Characters" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Question 2", each Text.End([Question], 1), type text),
    #"Inserted First Characters" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Last Characters", "Question ", each Text.Start([Question], Text.Length([Question])-1), type text),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted First Characters",{"Question"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"


then you can create measures
Total a = countx(FILTER('Table','Table'[Custom.1]="Yes"&&'Table'[Question 2]="a"),'Table'[Question])+0

Total b = countx(FILTER('Table','Table'[Custom.1]="Yes"&&'Table'[Question 2]="b"),'Table'[Question])+0

Total c = sumx(FILTER('Table','Table'[Question 2]="c"),'Table'[Custom])

Total d = sumx(FILTER('Table','Table'[Question 2]="d"),'Table'[Custom])



Thank you! There wouldn't be a way to do this in Table query though right? Those columns in my example are actually columns that I created in DAX.  If I have to I will just recreate them in Power Query but figured I'd ask just in case.  Thank you for your answer!
